# OrientDB: why always : Class already exists in current database

Tags: orientdb

I'm testing the OrientDB and unfamiliar with the OrientDB-Graph API. And now I copied the code on the net, it rises the Exception.
Next is my code:

```
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.*;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Element.*;
import java.util.*;

class OrientInsert {
        public static void testInsertion(OrientGraphNoTx graph) {
                System.out.println(new Date());
                int count  = 1000;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                        OrientVertex vertex1 = graph.addVertex("class:CLASS1", "prop1", Integer.toString(i), "prop2", "22", "prop3", "3333");
                        for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
                                OrientVertex vertex2 = graph.addVertex("class:CLASS2", "prop1", Integer.toString(i + j / 1000), "prop2", "22", "prop3", "3333");
                                graph.addEdge(null, vertex1, vertex2, "v1v2");
                        }
                }
                graph.commit();
                System.out.println(new Date());
        }

        public static  void main(String[] args) {
                OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:10.240.137.12/test", "admin", "admin");
                OrientGraphNoTx graph = factory.getNoTx();
                OrientInsert.testInsertion(graph);
        }       
}           `
```

And the output is:

```
    Mar 29, 2016 11:45:19 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=3,725MB (heap=14,288MB os=64,292MB disk=7,451MB)
Tue Mar 29 11:45:19 CST 2016
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Error on execution distributed COMMAND
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedStorage.command(ODistributedStorage.java:346)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:67)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1323)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:400)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:223)
        at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSchemaException: Class CLASS1 already exists in current database
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.doCreateClass(OSchemaShared.java:983)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.createClass(OSchemaShared.java:415)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaProxy.createClass(OSchemaProxy.java:127)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLCreateClass.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLCreateClass.java:179)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:90)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.task.OSQLCommandTask.execute(OSQLCommandTask.java:116)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.executeOnLocalNode(OHazelcastPlugin.java:810)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.ODistributedWorker.onMessage(ODistributedWorker.java:279)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.ODistributedWorker.run(ODistributedWorker.java:103)
```

Apparently, it first inserts the vertex1 and vertex2 into the graphDatabase, and creates class1 and class2. But when it comes to the second insertion, it still wants to create the class1 and class2. Why? how can i control the creation of class. But, so many users use this api for testing.

Comment: Hi @Qinger I tried your code and it works correctly for me

Comment: Thanks for your try. Do you run it on a standalone server or a distributed server cluster? Now, I am  running it on the cluster, which has three server   instance.

Comment: I run it on a standalone server, now i'm trying with a distributed server, I'll let you know ASAP

Comment: Hi, I tried in distributed mode with three node and it works, anyway which version are you using? Because I tried with 2.1.13

Comment: Very interesting. I tries with 2.1.12.. Do you run three node in three different machine or three node in one machine?

Comment: I used Oracle VM VirtualBox, so three node in one machine

Comment: Just finished testing with 2.1.12 and it works

Comment: @Qinger: Did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: this same issue happens with me for orient 3. Upon restart, the issue is fixed automatically? Anyone any clue about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:localhost/test", "admin", "admin");
        OrientGraphNoTx graph = factory.getNoTx();
        OrientInsert.testInsertion(graph);
        graph.shutdown();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("End main");

    }

    public static class OrientInsert {

        public static void testInsertion(OrientGraphNoTx graph) {
            System.out.println(new Date());
            int count  = 1000;

            //create class 1
            OClass clVertice1;
            OrientVertex vVertice1;

            clVertice1 = graph.createVertexType("CLASS1", "V");
            clVertice1.createProperty("prop1", OType.STRING);
            clVertice1.createProperty("prop2", OType.STRING);
            clVertice1.createProperty("prop3", OType.STRING);


            //create class 2
            OClass clVertice2;
            OrientVertex vVertice2;

            clVertice2 = graph.createVertexType("CLASS2", "V");
            clVertice2.createProperty("prop1", OType.STRING);
            clVertice2.createProperty("prop2", OType.STRING);
            clVertice2.createProperty("prop3", OType.STRING);


            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("i :"+i+" -------------------" );
                //....class 1
                vVertice1 = graph.addVertex("class:CLASS1");
                vVertice1.setProperties("prop1", Integer.toString(i));
                vVertice1.setProperties("prop2", "22"); 
                vVertice1.setProperties("prop3", "3333"); 

                for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
                    System.out.print("");
                    System.out.print(j+" ");
                    //...class 2
                    vVertice2 = graph.addVertex("class:CLASS2");
                    vVertice2.setProperties("prop1", Integer.toString(i + j / 1000));
                    vVertice2.setProperties("prop2", "22"); 
                    vVertice2.setProperties("prop3", "3333"); 

                    //edge                  
                    graph.addEdge(null, vVertice1, vVertice2, "v1v2");

                }
            }
        }

}
```

The result is this (i selected only 2 vertex with limit 100 E)
[image]